# Create event in hourly calendar in table view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, calendar

I am trying to create a daily calendar, like the native Apple one, that allows you to add an event that takes up part of a row or multiple rows. What would be the best way to go about doing this? I already have a table view built that displays the times by creating a custom separator line in each cell.

[image]

Should I be trying to use CGRect and create multiple prototype cells for each 15 minute interval (events will only be as granular as 15 min most likely)? Or would you layer a CGRect on top of the table view in a certain position? Events will not overlap each other, which should hopefully take some complexity out, e.g., not having to deal with events/blocks that are half the width.

Ideally, a blank row or an event should both be selectable so that an event can be added or edited, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Add two separate prototype cells one for no event and one for added event. You will of course have the data source array with you (I assume), from which you can detect for event is present on selected row in did select row.
Or else add flag for the same to check if event is added on particular cell index.

P.S. You can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension property for managing height for cells.

Comment: For the prototype cells, what would you use to show an event? A CGRect or a UI View? And how would you adjust for if the event lasts for the entire hour, or only goes for half of an hour? Is that a separate prototype cell?